# How to solve the equation to obtain the specified form?

Tags: equation-solving

Solve the equation to obtain such a result form;

```
Reduce[a x1 + x1^2 - a x2 - x2^2 - Log[x1] + Log[x2] == 0, 
  a] // Simplify

(*a\[Equal](-x1^2+x2^2+Log[x1]-Log[x2])/(x1-x2)||x1\[Equal]x2*)
```

How to obtain this form, that is, if a part can be omitted, it can be omitted

```
a == -x1 - x2 + (Log[x1] - Log[x2])/(x1 - x2)
```

want to get this result as following picture

[image]

Comment: Reduce[a x1 + x1^2 - a x2 - x2^2 - Log[x1] + Log[x2] == 0, a] // 
   Simplify // First

Comment: The part cannot be omitted, without hypothesis (classic student error, in the US, at least). `Solve` deletes full-dimension components, since it's less rigorous, as shown in current answers. `Or@@And@@@Apply[Equal,Solve[{x^2+y^2==4,x==y}],{2}]` converts to `Reduce` form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = Solve[a x1 + x1^2 - a x2 - x2^2 - Log[x1] + Log[x2] == 0, a][[1, 1]]
```

[image]

```
Apart[expr, x1]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ %
```

$a\to \frac{\log (\text{x1})-\log (\text{x2})}{\text{x1}-\text{x2}}-\text{x1}-\text{x2}$

Answer (score 6):

```
expr = First@
  Solve[a x1 + x1^2 - a x2 - x2^2 - Log[x1] + Log[x2] == 0, a]
```

$\left\{a\to \frac{-\text{x1}^2+\log (\text{x1})+\text{x2}^2-\log (\text{x2})}{\text{x1}-\text{x2}}\right\}$

```
r1 = Log[a_] - Log[b_] :> Log[a/b];
r2 = Log[a_/b_] :> Log[a] - Log[b];

(expr  /. r1 // Apart) /. r2
```

$\left\{a\to \frac{\log (\text{x1})-\log (\text{x2})}{\text{x1}-\text{x2}}-\text{x1}-\text{x2}\right\}$

Comment: (+1) Nice and simpler!

Comment: I am on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64,

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
expr1 = Solve[a x1 + x1^2 - a x2 - x2^2 - Log[x1] + Log[x2] == 0, 
    a][[1, 1]];

a -> ((-x1^2 + x2^2 + Log[x1] - Log[x2])/(
      x1 - x2) /. -x1^2 + x2^2 -> Factor[-x1^2 + x2^2] /. 
     x1 - x2 -> z // Expand) /. z -> x1 - x2

a -> -x1 - x2 + Log[x1]/(x1 - x2) - Log[x2]/(x1 - x2)
```

Have fun!